# GLM.fit() in Matlab vs. Python Statsmodels: why the different results?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, matlab, python, probit, statsmodels

**In what ways is Matlab's `glmfit` implemented differently than Python statsmodels' `GLM.fit()`?**

Here is a comparison of their results on my dataset: 
[image]
This represents graph 209 weights, generated from running GLM fit on:

`V`: (100000, 209) predictor variable (design matrix)

`y`: (100000,1) response variable

Sum of squared errors: 18.140615678

### A Specific Example

Why are these different? First, here's a specific example in Matlab:

```
yin = horzcat(y,ones(size(y)));
[weights_mat, d0, st0]=glmfit(V, yin,'binomial','probit','off',[],[],'off');
```

Let's try the equivalent in Python:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

## set up GLM
y = np.concatenate((y, np.ones( [len(y),1] )), axis=1)
sm_probit_Link = sm.genmod.families.links.probit
glm_binom = sm.GLM(sm.add_constant(y), sm.add_constant(V_design_matrix), family=sm.families.Binomial(link=sm_probit_Link))
     # statsmodels.GLM format: glm_binom = sm.GLM(data.endog, data.exog, family)

## Run GLM fit
glm_result = glm_binom.fit()
weights_py = glm_result.params 

## Compare the difference
weights_mat_import = Matpy.get_output('w_output.mat', 'weights_mat') # imports matlab variables
print SSE(weights_mat_import, weights_python)
```

### Let's Check The Docs

glmfit in Matlab:

`[b,dev,stats] = glmfit(X,y,distr)`

GLM.fit() setup in Python ([documentation](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLM.fit.html#statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLM.fit) ) :

`glm_model = sm.GLM(endog, exog, family=None, offset=None, exposure=None, missing='none', **kwargs)`

`glm_model.fit(start_params=None, maxiter=100, method='IRLS', tol=1e-08, scale=None, cov_type='nonrobust', cov_kwds=None, use_t=None, **kwargs)`

**Any pointers as to how to get Matlab `glmfit` results with Statsmodels?**

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same ling function, the `probit` part stands out.

Comment: Note that a software-specific issue like "In what ways is Matlab's glmfit implemented differently than Python statsmodels' GLM.fit()?" is not really on-topic here - see our [help/on-topic] for more information about the scope of our site. But I suspect you have an underlying statistical issue here - for instance as @MatthewDrury suggests, you may need to check your link function

Comment: @MatthewDrury Yes, I defined Link='probit' earlier; changed the code to show 'probit.'

Comment: @Silverfish I'm open to taking this question somewhere else; where else would you recommend?

Comment: Can you please add a reproducible example? Try something smaller first. (Off the bat, MATLAB is almost certainly ridiculously unit-tested and used in the industry for years so I would suggest you try to get Statsmodels to give MATLAB's output and not the other way around as you suggest)

Comment: The dependent variable (`endog`) is not correctly specified in the statsmodels example.